# Ionic Playground – ng-repeat instances' don't update $scope

Tags: angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a problem (using Ionic's Playground) with my ng-repeat instances not updating the controller's scope when new data is bound. I'm able to do exactly what I want within an actual Ionic app on my desktop and my device, but I can't seem to figure out why it won't work using Ionic's Playground. Here's my playground: http://play.ionic.io/app/9941cddae6bd

This is what it's supposed to do: https://youtu.be/9IJdpaZKDV4

Thanks!

edit: added video

edit again: more detail here — 
I now realize I should have been more specific in my question: the problem has to do with the this.checkForReorder function (lines 98-109 on mine). It won't fire because the tempToCompareIfNewOrder array doesn't represent the template instances' current values. The issue seems to be the instances' scopes don't update the controller's scope ie. if I console.table(tempToCompareIfNewOrder) (line 101 on mine) the logs are all always the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the console:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/BTCUSD=X/quote?format=json&view=detail. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://play.ionic.io' is therefore not allowed access.`

Followed by `TypeError: Cannot read property 'chg_percent' of undefined`.

Due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), your app cannot load the data it needs and your function stops due to an error. CORS kicks into action because you are loading from an API that didn't set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers to allow access from other domains.

Devices serve data over the `file` protocol, and the Ionic server does some stuff to get around CORS as well, so those two are fine.

Comment: The problem isn't with CORS, you may notice the comment I left at the top of the HTML file. If you're using chrome, you can use a plugin to enable CORS and it runs.

Answer (score 0):

It's loading the data initially, but, without spending too much time digging through your code, it doesn't seem to be reloading the data. Of course that could just be because the market's closed as I answer this.

If you got it working as a regular app, then it's likely a conflict between the sandbox and something in your script. An educated guess would be that the sandbox may have some restrictions in place to keep their site from getting hacked. It could also be that it's just not meant to handle anything that complex. It's just an easy way to get started without having to open a console, not really a place to move your code back to after you have.

If you must use Ionic's sandbox, I'd recommend breaking down your code and building it back up one piece at a time to find out what's in conflict.

If you can't get it working for love or money, you may want to try another sandbox tool like [codepen](http://codepen.io/).

If all of the above fails, you can just host the durned thing as a static web page somewhere like at [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/features.html#features-hosting)